# Django Jazzmin add button disappeared after adding mptt admin

Tags: python, django, django-mptt

I'm using jazzmin for django admin and mptt. After adding mptt to admin, in jazzmin theme add button disappeared.
I'm using latest versions of all libraries

```
class CustomMPTTModelAdmin(MPTTModelAdmin):
    # specify pixel amount for this ModelAdmin only:
    mptt_level_indent = 30


admin.site.register(Menu, CustomMPTTModelAdmin)
```

[Here you can see the admin where button disappeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKvLQ.jpg)

When I disable jazzmin or remove Mptt add button returns back on place

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # 'jazzmin',
    .....
]
```

[Here you can button returns back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ9q7.png)

There is also issue was opened on github
https://github.com/farridav/django-jazzmin/issues/126

but I could not find solution for this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the exact same issue while using `django-mptt` and `django-jazzmin` together. It seems that the admin template `admin/mptt-change-list.html` currently does not have the `{% change_list_object_tools %}` tag present, which causes the Add button to not be rendered.

**The solution is to override the `mptt-change-list.html` template with:**

```
{% extends "admin/mptt_change_list.html" %}
{% load admin_list i18n mptt_admin %}

{% block result_list %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
      {% block object-tools %}
        {% block object-tools-items %}
          {% change_list_object_tools %}
        {% endblock %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-12">
    {% mptt_result_list cl %}
    </div>
    {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.show_admin_actions %}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          {% admin_actions %}
        </div>
      </div>{% endif %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```